# How to load page in div for CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, html

I have layout [here](http://i48.tinypic.com/svs3kp.jpg) and I want to insert the [menu](http://i46.tinypic.com/4t6kd2.jpg) into the menu layout. Lately, I'm using frameset to solve this, but this time, I want to try using a `div` instead of frameset and also through CodeIgniter.

When the menu successful, so I can load the form to the form layout :D

How do I do this through CodeIgniter framework?

Comment: If you don't know how to do this, you don't understand the basics of MVC. I suggest you read through the [CodeIgniter documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/) (specifically the MVC parts).

Comment: I would guess by the structure of this question you aren't yet using codeigniter. Are you sure you're ready for that?

Comment: What code hav you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two choices  is to directly load the view inside the view like this

```
<div id="sidebar">

<?php $this->load->view('template/sidebar.php'); ?>

</div>
```

Or passing it as a variable from the controller and echo it in the view like this

```
function index(){

$data['sidebar'] = $this->_get_sidebar();
$this->load->view('home',$data);
}

function _get_sidebar(){

return $this->load->view('template/sidebar',TRUE);

}
```

and on the view

```
<div id="sample">
     <?php echo $sidebar;?>
</div>
```

Goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

You don't load *pages* inside a div, but **views**.
I would go like this:

Controller `main.php`

```
Class Main extends CI_Controller{

  function index()
  {
     $this->load->model('mymodel');
     $data['menu_items'] = $this->mymodel->get_menu();
     $this->load->view('layout', $data);
  }
}
```

Now you have the $menu_items variable available in your view layout.php. A neat approach would be to load "partials" view inside a "master" view (all views loaded inside another have the variable available to them).
SO, something like this:

views/layout.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title></title></head>
<body>
    <header>
      <?php $this->load->view('partials/header'); ?>
    </header>

    <section>
    <aside>
     <nav>
      <?php $this->load->view('partials/menu');?>
     </nav>
    </aside>
      <article>
        <?php $this->load->view('partials/content');?>
      </article>
    </section>
    <footer>
      <?php $this->load->view('partials/footer');?>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Now you create the partials inside the folder view/partials/, and they will have the variable passed in your controller to the layout view.

file `views/partials/menu.php`

```
<ul>
  <?php foreach($menu_items as $item): ?>
  <li><?php echo $item['name'];?></li>
  <?php endforeach;?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Don't you have to pass the `$data` variable into the view for it to be accessible?   
so  
`$this->load->view('layout')`
would be 
`$this->load->view('layout',$data);`

Comment: Of course, I just forgot to write it. Answer updated, thank you